# Insert NULL values into INT & STRING columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert null values ​​in integer and string columns but in the data set that it obtains before obtaining values ​​"---" for the case of string and "NA" for the case of INT, necessary when you have those values ​​are inserted as void I'm using SQL Sever and my query is like that.

```
INSERT INTO BOEMIC01
    (MICRO_DATE, MICRO_YEAR, MICRO_MONTH, MICRO_WEEK, MICRO_DIVISION, MICRO_SUBDIVISION, MICRO_CODE_COUNTRY, MICRO_COUNTRY, MICRO_CODE_CENTER, MICRO_CENTER, MICRO_FREQ, MICRO_TOTAL_M, MICRO_TOTAL_Y, MICRO_TOTAL_Z, MICRO_ID_PROCESS, MICRO_DESC_PROCESS, MICRO_TOTAL_A, MICRO_TOTAL_B, MICRO_TOTAL_C, MICRO_ID_POINT, MICRO_DESC_POINT, MICRO_CODE_MATERIAL, MICRO_DESC_MATERIAL, MICRO_TOTAL_D, MICRO_TOTAL_E, MICRO_TOTAL_F) VALUES
    (
        '2019-01-15',
        '2019',
        '1',
        '3',
        'X',
        'Y',
        'P001',
        'USA',
        'USA1',
        'USA2',
        'Daily',
        '2',
        '2',
        '0',
        '158',
        'Enva',
        '2',
        '2',
        '0',
        '344',
        '2',
        '---', --NULL
        '---', --NULL
        'NA', --NULL
        'NA', --NULL
        'NA' --NULL
    )
```

Comment: `NULLIF(StringColumn,'---'), NULLIF(IntColumn,'NA')`    ?

Comment: Where are you building the insert statement, as in where are the values '---' and 'N/A' coming from? You need to modify them before they get to the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

To insert `NULL` values use the `NULL` keyword.  As in:

```
insert into t (col)
    values (null);
```

To insert the default value, which is usually `null`, just leave the column out of the column list entirely:

```
insert into t (col1)
    values ('happy value');
```

`col2` will be set to its default value -- which is `NULL` if no other default is defined.

If you are inserting values from another source, then use `try_convert()` or `nullif()`  For example:

```
insert into t (col_str, col_int)
    values (nullif(@col_str, '---'), try_convert(int, @col_int));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as a matter of standard practice, you should always use *query parameters* to supply any literal values to your queries, to avoid "SQL injection" issues.  For instance, your query would now read:

```
INSERT INTO BOEMIC01
    (MICRO_DATE, MICRO_YEAR, MICRO_MONTH, [...]) 
    VALUES(?, ?, ? [...])
```

Notice the `?` symbols and notice also that they are not in quotes.

Then, when you *execute* the query, you supply both the SQL string and, separately, an array of values that are to be substituted for each `?` in order of occurrence.  Now, SQL cannot misinterpret any value as "part of the SQL," because it *isn't.*  Different sets of parameter values can be supplied to the same SQL string each time.

You *can* use functions such as `NULLIF()` as mentioned in BJones' comment:  `NULLIF('---', ?)` ... the parameter's value will be passed to the `NULLIF` function as its second argument.  I think that's a fine way to handle your requirement (and it should have been offered as "an answer").

Answer (score 0):

It really depends where the values are coming from, but if for example this insert is inside a Stored Procedure and the values are coming in via parameters then the following shows how to ensure `null` values for the cases specified. (Irrelevant columns left out for brevity):

```
INSERT INTO BOEMIC01 (... MICRO_CODE_MATERIAL, MICRO_DESC_MATERIAL, MICRO_TOTAL_D, MICRO_TOTAL_E, MICRO_TOTAL_F)
  select ...
    , case when @MICRO_CODE_MATERIAL != '---' then @MICRO_CODE_MATERIAL else null end
    , case when @MICRO_DESC_MATERIAL != '---' then @MICRO_CODE_MATERIAL else null end
    , try_convert(int, @MICRO_TOTAL_D)
    , try_convert(int, @MICRO_TOTAL_E)
    , try_convert(int, @MICRO_TOTAL_F)
```

However if you are passing this data from a client application then convert it client side.